# Display the current date in a text box after clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date-formatting

I'm building a form to standardize filenames (I'm a video editor). After a lot of research, copying, pasting and testing I'm almost there. I just need to display the current date at the end of the filename after the user clicks on the corresponding checkbox.

The HTML has the code to get the current date and to format it as I want (YYMMDD), b*ut for the life of me I can't find a way to display it at the end of the filename*. The code to display the date works because I can enable/disable text, but I can't display the result of the todaysdate function.

This is the code to get the current date and format it to YYMMDD:

```
function SetDate()
{
var date = new Date();

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear() - 2000;


if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;


var today = year + month + day;


document.getElementById('today').value = today;
}
```

This is the code that adds or removes the date at the end of the filename when you click the checkbox.

```
function todaysdate()
{
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('todayis');
    if (checkbox.checked != false)
        document.getElementById('todayis').value = "DATE";
    if (checkbox.checked != true)
        document.getElementById('todayis').value = "";
}
```

This is the code for the checkbox:

```
Add date (YYMMDD): <input type="checkbox" onclick="todaysdate()" id="todayis" value="" />
```

**Thanks in advance for your help.**

Edit: Added the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `todaysdate` function you set the value of the `todayis` input to `DATE`, where you should be setting it to the value of your date calculation. Here’s just a little change to what you have that should probably work!

```js
function todaysdate()
{
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('todayis');
  if (checkbox.checked != false)
    document.getElementById('todayis').value = getDate();
  else if (checkbox.checked != true)
    document.getElementById('todayis').value = "";
}

function getDate()
{
  var date = new Date();

  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear() - 2000;

  if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
  if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

  var today = year + "" + month + "" + day;
  return today;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the php function Time:

Set the timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

And get the actual date:

```
$date_now = date('Y/m/d', time());
```

So, to set the value on the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $date_now ?>" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that PHP is relevant at all in the context of this question...?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getYYMMDDDate(date) {
    var year = String(date.getFullYear()).substring(2,4);
    var month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    var day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2,"0");
    return year + month + day;
}


...
// change this document.getElementById('todayis').value = "DATE";
document.getElementById('todayis').value = getYYMMDDDate(new Date());
```

Comment: THIS WORKS!!! I'm so happy.